# Can't connect to pigpio at localhost(8888)

Tags: pi-3, pigpio, gpiozero

So I don't think this issue is related necessarily to my code, because I'm thrown this error even running some formally working code examples from my textbook (Practical Python Programming for IoT):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Can't connect to pigpio at localhost(8888)

Did you start the pigpio daemon? E.g. sudo pigpiod

Did you specify the correct Pi host/port in the environment
variables PIGPIO_ADDR/PIGPIO_PORT?
E.g. export PIGPIO_ADDR=soft, export PIGPIO_PORT=8888

Did you specify the correct Pi host/port in the
pigpio.pi() function? E.g. pigpio.pi('soft', 8888)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pypi/images/test1.py", line 33, in <module>
    Device.pin_factory = PiGPIOFactory() #set gpiozero to use pigpio by default.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/pigpio.py", line 126, in __init__
    raise IOError('failed to connect to %s:%s' % (host, port))
OSError: failed to connect to localhost:8888
```

I'm a super novice and I'm attempting to make a pseudo-robot that when you press a button, a red led will light up (to signal that it's recording) and record 5 seconds of audio. It will then take that audio, convert it to text, then run said text through [DeepAi's GPT3 text generator](https://deepai.org/machine-learning-model/text-generator), return the new text, and play it out a speaker with Googles TTS. I'm running a Raspberry Pi 3 with Bullseye. If anyone knows of a solution to this problem, which I believe is system based and not code based (though if you have solutions/tips for my shitty code I'd more than welcome that too), I'd greatly appreciate it.

Here's my code below:

```
 #https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/using-speech-recognition-to-convert-speech-to-text-python
    #https://classes.engineering.wustl.edu/ese205/core/index.php?title=Audio_Input_and_Output_from_USB_Microphone_%2B_Raspberry_Pi

import speech_recognition as sr
import requests
# Import the required module for text 
# to speech conversion
from gtts import gTTS 
# This module is imported so that we can 
# play the converted audio
import os

#GPIO/Pi dependcies 
#from gpiozero import Device, LED, Button                                                 # (1)
#from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory
#import signal     

import random
import time
import wave
import io
import requests

from gpiozero import Device, LED, Button                                                 # (1)
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory
import signal         

#intializing pin numbers
LED_GPIO_PIN = 21
BUTTON_GPIO_PIN = 23

Device.pin_factory = PiGPIOFactory() #set gpiozero to use pigpio by default.

filename = "helloWorld.wav"

# initialize the recognizer
r = sr.Recognizer()
#initialize text variable
text = ''


def pressed():
    time.sleep(.5)
    led.on()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
    # read the audio data from the default microphone
        mic_audio_data = r.record(source, duration=5)
    print("Recognizing...")
    # convert speech to text
    micText = r.recognize_google(mic_audio_data)
    
    time.sleep(5)
    led.off()

    # ------------------- TEXT TO DEEP AI -------------------

    r = requests.post(
        "https://api.deepai.org/api/text-generator",
        data={
            'text': micText,
        },
        headers={'api-key': '4588448a-9284-4401-b3cb-552695a96edc'}
    )
    print(r.json())
    json = r.json()
    micOutput = json.get('output')


    # ------------------- TEXT TO SPEECH -------------------

    # Language in which you want to convert
    language = 'en'
    
    # Passing the text and language to the engine, 
    # here we have marked slow=False. Which tells 
    # the module that the converted audio should 
    # have a high speed
    myobj = gTTS(text=micOutput, lang=language, slow=False)
    
    # Saving the converted audio in a mp3 file named
    # welcome 
    myobj.save("micOutput.wav")
    
    # Playing the converted file
    os.system("mpg123 micOutput.wav")

led = LED(LED_GPIO_PIN)
button = Button(BUTTON_GPIO_PIN, pull_up=True, bounce_time=0.1) # Bounce time in seconds 

button.when_pressed = pressed                                                                         

signal.pause()
```

Comment: Did you start the **pigpio daemon**? E.g. sudo pigpiod What **OS**? What does `sudo ss -lntup | grep 8888` show?

Comment: sudo pigpiod worked! thank you! i dunno why i decided to do such a big project outside of my wheelhouse. appreciate you <3

Comment: `pigpiod` is an excellent tool, but frankly not the easiest to use and sparsely documented. If using `gpiozero` I suggest you stick with the default pin factory (RPi.GPIO) unless you need to so something more exotic.